# How to set swipe to delete UITableview frame height in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

The Swipe delete button shows depends on `TableviewCell` Height. 
Need to reduce the height of the delete button.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to change native controls, but you still can do it by subclassing `UITableViewCell`

```
@implementation UITableViewCellSubclass

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (self.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
        if ([self.subviews count] < 4) return;
        UIView *deleteButton = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:3];
        deleteButton.frame = CGRectOffset(deleteButton.frame, 10, 10);
    }
}

@end
```

But, it is very bad way to handle it. Better create custom `UITableViewCell` with custom behaviour and custom delete `UIButton` and then do whatever you want with it.